# Put nested field result into single string

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I've got this query (nevermind the fact it's not properly normalised):

```
Select Name, (Select FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c, FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c 
              FROM Flight_Bookings__r) 
FROM Opportunity 
Where id='00XX00000XXXXXXXXX'
```

And results:

```
[{"FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c":"BA713","FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c":"BA712"},
{"FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c":"BA713","FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c":"BA712"},
{"FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c":"LX332","FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c":"LX317"}]
```

What I want to have (must be deduped):

```
string Flight_No = 'BA713, BA712, LX332, LX317'
```

Visualforce page prints the results in the following manner:

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        Check Out Date
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:outputField value="{!o.opportunity.O_CheckOut_Date__c}" />
</apex:column>
```

I presume I will need some sort of loop to assign all the values to one string?

My trouble is that the query is executed in the following way (SOQL query is built based on several conditions):

```
for(Opportunity opp : database.Query(strQry)){
    BulkEmail b = new BulkEmail();
    b.opportunity = opp;
    listBulkEmail.add(b);
}
```

Any ideas? Perhaps I should post more code?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: use of the wrapper class

Apex:

```
public with sharing YourClass{

    public List<MyWrapper> allOpps { get; set; }

    public YourClass(){
        allOpps = new List<MyWrapper>();
    }

    public class MyWrapper{
        public Opportunity opp { get; set; }
        public String flightNumbers { get; set; }

        public MyWrapper(Opportunity o, String s){
            this.opp = o;
            this.flightNumbers = s;
        }
    }

    for(Opportunity opp : database.Query(strQry)){
        BulkEmail b = new BulkEmail();
        b.opportunity = opp;
        listBulkEmail.add(b);

        if(!opp.Flight_Bookings__r.isEmpty()){
            String numbers = '';
            for(Flight_Booking__c fb : opp.Flight_Bookings__r){
                if(!numbers.containsIgnoreCase(fb.FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c)){
                    numbers += fb.FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c + ',';
                }
                if(!numbers.containsIgnoreCase(fb.FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c)){
                    numbers += fb.FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c + ',';
                }
            }

        }
            else {
                numbers = 'There is no data.';
            }

            allOpps.add( new MyWrapper(opp, numbers) );
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allOpps}" var="o">
    <apex:column value="{!o.opp.Name}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Flight numbers">
        <apex:outputText value="{!o.flightNumbers}">
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

---

The easiest way to do this is use your loop and add another loop to collect values from the subquery:

```
String Flight_No = '';

for(Opportunity opp : database.Query(strQry)){
    BulkEmail b = new BulkEmail();
    b.opportunity = opp;
    listBulkEmail.add(b);

    if(!opp.Flight_Bookings__r.isEmpty()){
        for(Flight_Bookings__c fb : opp.Flight_Bookings__r){
            if(!Flight_No.containsIgnoreCase(fb.FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c)){
                Flight_No += fb.FLB_Inbound_Flight_No__c + ',';
            }
            if(!Flight_No.containsIgnoreCase(fb.FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c)){
                Flight_No += fb.FLB_Outbound_Flight_No__c + ',';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to change to `Flight_Booking__c` instead of `Flight_Bookings__c` (funny how SF force you to flip between plural and singular field names depending on query type). I have added to my VF page: `<apex:outputField value="{!o.opportunity.Flight_No}" />`. But now I am still getting an `Error: Could not resolve field 'Flight_No' from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!o.opportunity.Flight_No}' in page ReportS..S..t`

Comment: @Dzh you need to use outputText instead: <apex:outputText value="{!Fligt_No}" /> And declair this variable like public String Flight_no { get; set;} in controller.

Comment: I did declare the variable in the start. Trying to use outputText throws me an error in actual VF page: `Attempt to de-reference a null object`.

Comment: You need to set this variable in constructor first like `Flight_No = '';`

Comment: Ok. I've tested this with production data and it doesn't return what I really wanted. It puts all Flight No's into one string, rather than for each line.

Comment: @Dzh You need a wrapper class then.

Comment: @Dzh Updated my answer

Comment: Now I just get `Variable does not exist: numbers.`